# Inverted SQL query

Tags: sql

I've got the following tables:

**Table1 {ArticleNo (int), ArtDescription (string) }**

**Table2 { ArticleNo (int), Year (date) }**

Table1.ArticleNo is a primary key.
Table2.ArticleNo is a foreign key referenced to table1.ArticleNo

It's  difficult to explain what I want to query, so here a short example:

---

**Table1**

```
(1,Desk)
(2,Chair)
(3,Ruler)
```

**Table2**

```
(1,2000)
(1,2000)
(2,2001)
```

The query should return:

```
1 Desk 2001
2 Chair 2000
3 Ruler 2000
3 Ruler 2001
```

All articles which are not sold (or whatever) in all years (all years from table2).

---

I hope you understand  my example - the query seems to be very complex. Here my approach to a solution:

```
SELECT table1.ArticleNo,table1.ArtDescription,table2.Year
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.ArticleNo=table2.ArticleNo
WHERE NOT table1.ArticleNo IN (SELECT table2.Year FROM table2);
```

I tried lots of different things.. I hope you can help me!

Comment: I think you might want to rethink your table schemas.  This is going to get very complex very quickly and doesn't provide any immediate benefit.  Perhaps your second table should be the years in which the items are sold, as opposed to not sold.

Comment: In your example on the line "WHERE NOT table1.ArticleNo IN (SELECT table2.Year FROM table2);" you're comparing ArticleNo to a Year. From your data example that will never match.

Comment: Which database engine are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  t1.*, t2.year
FROM    t1
CROSS JOIN
        (
        SELECT  DISTINCT year
        FROM    t2
        ) t2
WHERE   (t1.id, t2.year) NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  t2.id, t2.year
        FROM    t2
        )
```

Create an index on `t2 (year, id)` (in this order) for the query to work fast.

Comment: Thanks for your help! And sorry about the bad formatting - now I know how to do that better.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `cross join` to create a list of all item+year combinations.  Then you could filter the rows without sales with a `not exists` condition:

```
select  *
from    t1 items1
cross join    
        (
        select  distinct year
        from    t2 sales1
        ) sales2
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    t2 sales3
        where   sales3.ItemId = items1.ItemId
                and sales3.Year = sales2.Year
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of ways of doing this.  Two examples:

```
select
  t1.ArtDescription,
  y.Year
from
  Table1 t1
  join (
    select distinct
      t2.Year
    from
      Table2 t2
  ) y on 1=1
where
  not exists (
    select
      1
    from
      Table2 tx2
    where
      tx2.ArticleNo = t1.ArticleNo and tx2.Year = y.Year)
```

Oracle (SQL Server can do the same thing, use `EXCEPT` instead of `MINUS`):

```
select
  t1.ArtDescription,
  y.Year
from
  Table1 t1
  join (
    select distinct
      t2.Year
    from
      Table2 t2
  ) y on 1=1
MINUS
select
  t12.ArtDescription
  t22.Year
from
  Table1 t12
  join Table2 t22 on t12.ArticleNo = t22.ArticleNo
```

Comment: Nice one, I think you can write it a little more clearly by replacing the "`join ... on 1=1`" with a "`cross join`"

Comment: ahh.. the first one doesn't look that complex. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.ArticleNo,table1.ArtDescription,table2.Year
    FROM table1 CROSS JOIN table2 
    WHERE table1.ArticleNo != table2.ArticleNo order by table1.ArticleNo;
```